# Return an element based on another element in a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list with nested lists. The 1st element in each nest belongs to each other.
The nested lists are expandable.
I'm trying to return one element if I call its associated element.

I can list them using indexes but as the nest is expandable that won't work

I put a sandbox box on [here](https://repl.it/@louis_philippedescamps/Nested-Lists).

```
nested = [['nest1_A', 'nest1_B', 'nest1_C'], ['nest2_A', 'nest2_B', 'nest2_C'], ['nest3_A', 'nest3_B', 'nest3_C']]

print(nested,'\n')

print('First Set')
print(nested[0][0])
print(nested[1][0])
print(nested[2][0],'\n')

print('Second Set')
print(nested[0][1])
print(nested[1][1])
print(nested[2][1],'\n')

print('Third Set')
print(nested[0][2])
print(nested[1][2])
print(nested[2][2],'\n')

print('And so on...')
```

I expect that if I call 
`nest1_A[0]` it will return `nest2_A` and 
`nest1_A[1]` it will return `nest3_A`

Comment: What do you mean by `call nest1_A[0]`?

Comment: What do you mean by calling `nest_A[0]` ? To me it seems like you want to get all elements A, then all B, then all C and so on... Maybe with each nest having different length (for instance nest3 could be missing its C and stop at B). Is that right ?

Comment: by calling nest_A[0], I mean something like this print([nested[1][0] for x in nested[0][0]])

Comment: each nest will have 3 elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function that loops the master list and gets the sub list item at the index you feed to it.

```py
def get_nested_elements_by_index(nested_list, index):
    output_list = []
    for sub_list in nested_list:
        if len(sub_list) > index:
            output_list.append(sub_list[index])
    return output_list


nested = [
    ["nest1_A", "nest1_B", "nest1_C"],
    ["nest2_A", "nest2_B", "nest2_C"],
    ["nest3_A", "nest3_B", "nest3_C"],
]

print(
    "First set:\n{first}\n\nSecond set:\n{second}\n\nThird set:\n{third}\n".format(
        first="\n".join(get_nested_elements_by_index(nested, 0)),
        second="\n".join(get_nested_elements_by_index(nested, 1)),
        third="\n".join(get_nested_elements_by_index(nested, 2)),
    )
)
```

You can improve the function using list comprehension like this:

```py
def get_nested_elements_by_index(nested_list, index):
    return [sub_list[index] for sub_list in nested_list if len(sub_list) > index]
```

Which lets you even forget the function and just use it as is.
For example, for index of `0` you can write

```
...
        first="\n".join(sub_list[0] for sub_list in nested_list),
...
```

(the last example is an iterator inside a join function but it works pretty much the same like list comprehension)

Comment: i would put nest1_B[0] and it would return nest2_B

Comment: sorry, what is `nest1_B` ? I'm trying to understand but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: nest1_B is nested[0][1] and belongs to nested[1][1] and nested[2][1]

Comment: where would `nest76_X` belong then ?

Comment: i dont have nest76_X

Comment: @reportgunner see the comment on my answer, he wants the elements in`nested[0]` to be iterators over `nested[1:][x]` where `x` is the index for A,  B or C.

Comment: @Plopp I saw the comment, good point. What is confusing me is the letter in the name `nest1_B` as it seems to have some significance for OP

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want ?

```
def get_nest(nests, id):
    return [x[id] for x in nests if len(x) > id]
```

It gives those results:

```
get_nest(nested, 1)
>>> ['nest1_B', 'nest2_B', 'nest3_B']
```

And if you have a different sized nested list (if not you can drop the `if` part in the method):

```
nested = [['nest1_A', 'nest1_B', 'nest1_C'], ['nest2_A', 'nest2_B', 'nest2_C'], ['nest3_A', 'nest3_B']]
get_nest(nested, 2)
>>>['nest1_C', 'nest2_C']
```

EDIT: Removed hints in method definition

Comment: i would put nest1_B[0] and it would return nest2_B

Comment: Do you want the elements in the first nest `nested[0]` to be objects you can call like variables ? Like doing `nest1_B[0]` being the equivalent of `nested[1][1]` ?